# jquery full calendar : Different color randomly for each event from MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

I am starting to use jQuery [full calendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) and creating the event in MySQL database. I would like the calendar events to have different colour randomly. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
<?php if ($event[$j]['allday'] == 0){?>
    { title: '[<?php echo $event[$j]['courseid'];?> by <?php echo $event[$j]['tutorid'];?>]',
    start: new Date(start_year[<?php echo $j?>],
                    start_month[<?php echo $j?>]-1,
                    start_day[<?php echo $j?>],
                    start_hour[<?php echo $j?>],
                    start_mins[<?php echo $j?>]),
    end: new Date(end_year[<?php echo $j?>],
                  end_month[<?php echo $j?>]-1,
                  end_day[<?php echo $j?>],
                  end_hour[<?php echo $j?>],
                  end_mins[<?php echo $j?>]),
    url: 'mg_course.php?courseid=<?php echo $event[$j]['courseid']; ?>'
    },                  
<?php };
if ($event[$j]['allday'] == 1) {?>
    { title: '[<?php echo $event[$j]['courseid'];?> by <?php echo $event[$j]['tutorid'];?>]',
    start: new Date(start_year[<?php echo $j?>],
                    start_month[<?php echo $j?>]-1,
                    start_day[<?php echo $j?>],
                    start_hour[<?php echo $j?>],
                    start_mins[<?php echo $j?>]),
    end: new Date(end_year[<?php echo $j?>],
                  end_month[<?php echo $j?>]-1,
                  end_day[<?php echo $j?>],
                  end_hour[<?php echo $j?>],
                  end_mins[<?php echo $j?>]),
    url: 'mg_course.php?courseid=<?php echo $event[$j]['courseid']; ?>',
    allDay: 'false'
},      
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: can add display properties to event  object  http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/#color-options

Comment: I can display on the screen. However, I add the background colour after "allDay: 'false'", it does not display any more.

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here is I created the demo on http://113.28.30.89/test/db_display2.php Please have a look and help!!

Comment: demo doesn't have any display properties in event objects

Comment: All events are from mysql database. I'd like to know how to set different colour randomly on each event. Thanks.

Comment: add property to event object as per the docs

Comment: I am not sure how to do it?

Comment: I need to show on http://113.28.30.89/test/Images/test.jpg

Comment: Anyone can be help and I will be appreciated with any advice. Thanks!!